# Problems using INNER JOIN with using Composite Key

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm quite new to SQL and very new (learning today in fact!) how to use JOINS or in particular INNER JOIN. I have read some guides but haven't seen any helpful information for when one has a table with a composite key.

### Tables:

```
Matches

+-----------+------------+
| (MatchID) | StartTime  |
+-----------+------------+
| 548576804 | 1393965361 |
| 548494906 | 1393123251 |
+-----------+------------+
```

And

```
+-----------------------------------+---------+
| (PlayerID)    -     (MatchID)    |   Result |
+-----------------------------------+---------+
| 38440257            548576804    |   Win    |
| 17164642            548494906    |   Loss   |
+-----------------------------------+---------+
```

Of the above tables, The `MatchID` in table `Matches` is a Foreign Key.

### Problem

The columns in the parenthesis are Keys (so the composite key is in the MatchDetails table). I am trying to pull all of the Matches played by player 38440257, and the StartTime from the Matches table. The first Join I tried worked, however it pulled every game, regardless of player:

```
SELECT matchdetails.MatchID,
       matches.StartTime,
       matchdetails.Result
FROM matchdetails,
     matches
WHERE matchdetails.MatchID = matches.MatchID
ORDER BY matches.StartTime ASC
```

Now, I am not sure how to add in the point that I want ONLY matches from a particular playerID in the query. Because the following does not work:

```
SELECT matchdetails.MatchID,
       matches.StartTime,
       matchdetails.Result
FROM matchdetails,
     matches
WHERE matchdetails.MatchID = matches.MatchID,
      matchdetails.PlayerID=76561197998705985
ORDER BY matches.StartTime ASC
```

In addition, the JOIN I am using above, is there an easier way to write it that I am missing? Or am I not writing a Join at all? I followed one of the queries from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38578/3189588), which stated they were equivalent queries. However it feels rather cumbersome to write.

Please let me know if I have neglected any information.

Comment: Does the nonworking section return an error or incorrect data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need `AND` between your predicates:

```
SELECT matchdetails.MatchID,
       matches.StartTime,
       matchdetails.Result
FROM matchdetails,
     matches
WHERE matchdetails.MatchID = matches.MatchID
      AND matchdetails.PlayerID=76561197998705985
ORDER BY matches.StartTime ASC;
```

However, I would highly recommend you [move away from the ANSI 89 JOIN syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) and adopt ANSI 92 instead. As the names suggest, the syntax you have used is over 20 years out of date.

```
SELECT matchdetails.MatchID,
       matches.StartTime,
       matchdetails.Result
FROM matchdetails
     INNER JOIN matches
        ON matchdetails.MatchID = matches.MatchID
WHERE matchdetails.PlayerID=76561197998705985
ORDER BY matches.StartTime ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you for the concise reply. I did think there was something not quite right about my JOIN query, but I wasn't sure what it was or how to find out what the problem was. I will change to the newer version and read up on it!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT matchdetails.MatchID,
       matches.StartTime,
       matchdetails.Result
FROM matchdetails 
     JOIN ON matchdetails.MatchID = matches.MatchID
WHERE
      matchdetails.PlayerID=76561197998705985
ORDER BY matches.StartTime ASC
```